# XPage context.getHistoryUrl(1) returning different Pages Firefox and IE

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib, xpages-ssjs

I have 3 XPages one to edit documents and two displaying several views in a `xe:dynamicContent` lets call them xpView1 and xpView2. When clicking on a document link in the view the user gets redirected to the first XPage where he can edit the document.

The thing is that in IE when the user gets redirected from xpView1 to the edidXPage I get the right Page. But when the users gets redirected from xpView2 to the edidXPage (also using IE) i get the main.xsp which has nothing to do with one of the other three.

I Use `context.gethistoryUrl(1)` to determine where he comes from and in Firefox everything works fine but not in IE when coming from xpView2. The XPages are nearly the same containing a `xe:layout` a `xe:dynamicContent` and about three different `xe:dataView`. Also the links which are redirecting the users are exact the same:

In xpView1:

```
<xp:link id="Subject">
    <xp:this.text><![CDATA[#{javascript:@NormalizeSubject(viewEntry.getColumnValue("Subject")) }]]></xp:this.text>
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"/editDocument.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=" + viewEntry.getUniversalID()}]]>
</xp:this.value></xp:link>
```

In XpView2:

```
<xp:link escape="true" id="link1">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"/editDocument.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=" + viewEntry.getUniversalID()}]]></xp:this.value>
<xp:text escape="false" id="lateTitle" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:12pt;">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript::@NormalizeSubject(viewEntry.getColumnValue("Subject"))}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
</xp:link>
```

On the editXPage I placed a `<xp:text>` to check the output. But all I can see is that if I use IE only xpView1 is working and if I use Firefox both are working!?!

```
<xp:text>
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return "History(1): "+context.getHistoryUrl(1); }]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
```

It would be to much code if I post all 3 XPages so I just want to know what I have to look for (PartialRefresh or some xp:DataView properties which causes such trouble)

Comment: Did you try referrer? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp

Comment: Also, look for address bar prior to opening second page. Are there differences?

Comment: @Frantisek Kossuth, thx for the hint. I added the <script> to my edit XPage and it returns the right Page in both browsers when redirecting from both sites (xpView1 & xpView2), but i cant use it in the SSJS. The bar looks the same everything seems equal.

Comment: Is there xpView1.xsp or xpView2.xsp as part of the url in browser, when you click your actions pointing to editDocument.xsp? It seems you get url without page name, therefore back link opens page defined in "Launch options" of database. It seem to be browser specific bug, someone from IBM should look at it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally; I found the answer my self.

In xpView2 in some cases the view is displaying images in the summery section. If that hapens i used a customControl wich adds a lightbox javascript wich handls the display of the image.

I dont know why this js is interfering with the context.getHistory(1) and I dont know why it is only in IE. But i know i have to remove it or find a workaround.